# Is there a way to filter specific rows, if they contain "NA"?

Tags: r, filter, case, na

I tidy an excel sheet, in which are empty rows that I want to exclude. One column contains "NA" as character so I tried to use filter in case that NA can be detected.

I tried to use some function with filter(case_when) in combination with grepl("NA", col), which did not quite work out.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Try using `is.na(col)` to return empty cells. Also `na.omit()` will remove the entire row if ANY cell contains an NA. Be wary that THE WHOLE ROW is removed!!!!

Comment: `df[!grepl("NA", df$col), ]`. although you might wanna convert "NA"s to NAs first to make it easier (e.g. using `anyNA`)